# Select an element from each matrix row/column specified by a vector

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

Let's say we have a matrix (or an arbitrary 2+D list) `x` and an integer vector `l` of the same length. What is the most elegant way to get a list `{x[[1,l[[1]]]], x[[2, l[[2]]]],...}`? The best solution I can think about is

```
x[[#, l[[#]]]]&/@Range@Length@x
```

, but I'm sure there should be a much easier/more elegant way.

Comment: Can you give an example of list x and vector l? It's not completely clear to me what "l" is. It also seems to me that l needs an additional condition, i.e. it's elements must be less or equal then the 2+D dimension of the matrix

Comment: `x` is an arbitrary matrix, e.g. `x = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {3, 3}]`. `l` is a list of integers with the same length as `x`, e.g. `l={1,2,2}`. Yes, this additional condition is required if we want the code to be evaluated without errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant way to do that, but it is descently efficient to use `Extract`:

```
m = 1000;
n = 2000;
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, n}];
l = RandomInteger[{1, n}, m];

a = x[[#, l[[#]]]] & /@ Range@Length@x; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = Flatten@MapIndexed[x[[#2, #1]] &, l]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
c = Extract[x, Transpose[{Range[Length[l]], l}]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b == c
```

> 0.140761
>
> 0.002416
>
> 0.000067
>
> True

Answer (score 6):

```
MapIndexed[x[[#2, #1]] &, l]
```

An example:

```
SeedRandom[90]; x = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {3, 3}]
l = {1, 2, 2};
MapIndexed[x[[#2, #1]] &, l]
```

> {{0.647385, 0.307327, 0.702473}, {0.656437, 0.675096, 
>     0.0759657}, {0.733796, 0.139355, 0.0910026}}
>
> {{0.647385}, {0.675096}, {0.139355}}

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
MapThread[#1[[#2]]&, {x,l}]
```

or equivalently

```
MapThread[
  With[{f = #1, x = #2}, 
    Construct[f[[#]] &, x]] &, {x, l}]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ReplacePart`

```
list = {{9, 7, 8}, {3, 9, 4}, {8, 2, 5}};
p = {1, 2, 2};

ReplacePart[x, i_ :> list[[i, p[[i]]]]]
```

{9, 9, 2}